# Flexbox - justify-content: center and align-items: center not working?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a pretty basic flex setup and, for whatever reason, the div in question won't vertically center inside its parent tag. You can see the isolated test case below.

```css
.likeness-rank-table {
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: block;
}
.likeness-rank-table .col {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 20%;
  min-height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.likeness-rank-table .col .col-inner {
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 150px;
}
.likeness-rank-table .likeness-rank-table-body {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #a2a5a7;
}
.draggable-tags .draggable-tag {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.draggable-tag {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.draggable-tag .draggable-tag-inner {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: #63b3ce;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="likeness-rank-table">
  <div class="likeness-rank-table-body">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="col-inner droppable">
        <div class="draggable-tag ui-draggable">
          <div class="draggable-tag-inner">
            This Blue Box Should Be Horizontally and Vertically Centered Inside The Big White Box But It's Not
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a codepen to see it:

http://codepen.io/trevorhinesley/pen/grQKPO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are certain flex properties that are applicable only on flex items, while others are only applicable on flex containers.

The `align-items` and `justify-content` properties apply only to flex containers. Yet, you are using them on a flex item...

```
.likeness-rank-table .col .col-inner {
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 150px;
}
```

... so they are being ignored.

You need to add `display: flex` to the rule above. That will get `align-items: center` to work.

However, `justify-content: center` will continue to fail because the parent  has a `max-width: 20%` limiting horizontal movement.

```
.likeness-rank-table .col {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 20%;            /* limits horizontal centering of child element */
  min-height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

So, apply the horizontal centering to the parent another level up.

```
.likeness-rank-table .likeness-rank-table-body {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #a2a5a7;
  justify-content: center;    /* new */
}
```

[**Revised Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNXrwY?editors=1100)

Here's a useful list of flex properties broken down by parent and child: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

You need to `@include flex` on your `col-inner` (line 40 of your scss), as `align-items` and `justify-content` only work on the flexbox element ([see this handy guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)).

Then to align the `.col` element within the big white box you can add `justify-content: center` to `.likeness-rank-table-body` on line 47 of your scss.